# Seleccionar un label al hacer presión con el dedo con swift

Tags: swift, swift2, swift3

Es posible que se seleccione un label al hacer presion con el dedo?

En `android` en muchas app al hacer presion con el dedo se selecciona una parte del `label` y luego lo puedes copiar o compartir.

Pero no se si en `IOS` se puede hacer

Comment: ¿Que quieres copiar el texto de una label presionando con el dedo?

Comment: Mas o menos si, que salga como en `android` si se puede que aparezca el pequeño menu de copiar, compartir, ... @Error404

Comment: Por defecto no lo puedes hacer. Al menos, lo acabo de probar y no me sale ese menú contextual.

Comment: Entonces tendria que añadir un evento tactil con las acciones no?? @Error404 gracias!

Comment: Si, entiendo que sí. La verdad que no tengo mucha experiencia en Swift pero ahora lo he probado con un iphone y no se podía seleccionar la label. Sin embargo, si que me suena que hay eventos para detectar cuando presionas con el dedo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No se puede con un `UILabel`, en su caso, tienes que usar el `UITextView`. Asegurate que no sea editable `(.editable = NO)`. De ésta manera, tiene apariencia de texto como el `UILabel`, y lo puedes copiar sin problemas

Comment: Perfecto, gracias, ha funcionado

Comment: Subir puntos a las respuestas que funcionan mola!